# Why do some battery-powered devices shut down at high power levels?

Tags: battery, battery-life

I have a laptop that consistently shuts down at about 60% battery. No warning, no "shutting down" screen, just an instant loss of power. This is an HP laptop running Ubuntu, if it matters.

I also have an Android phone (LG G4) that shuts down at around 30% battery. No warning, no shutting down message, but I do get a "0% power too low to power on" screen.

The questions are this:

- Why are these devices shutting down at such high power levels?
- Do they have faulty batteries?
- Are they actually at 0% when it's showing 30% or 60%?
- Why does the BIOS of my LG G4 display 0% when it dies, but not Android?
- If the devices consistently die at a certain power level, why don't the OSes correct for the error in reported battery percentage?

Comment: I can answer a few of your questions:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be for a number of reasons you have provided above, but to try explain the problem -

As the battery gets older, it may not be able to produce the current needed at the required voltage.  When this happens, things crash.   The answer could, therefor be "you have a faulty battery", but really, its more an old battery which is not capable of performing.   It is also possible that some of the cells in the battery are working, but one isn't.  If this is the case, that 1 cell is putting a huge extra power draw.

They are probably at 30/60% - this being a metric related to the voltage (which is an indicator of how much charge is stored), but not the current.  It is possible that the firmware is incorrectly defining the low and high voltages, which means that from a use point of view they are at 0%.   Its also possible its a calibration error on your Android phone.  [Follow the guide](https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-calibrate-the-battery-on-your-android-device) at this page to do it.